# insert to a simply linked list (everywhere, front, end, middle)

Tags: c, function, insert, singly-linked-list

I want some help in a function.

I want to write a function which insert in a linked list. But not just in the middle, it have to work if  it have to insert to the fronr or the end.

Structure:

```
    typedef struct ranklist {
        int point;
        char* name;
        struct ranklist *next;
    } ranklist;
```

A started to work on it, but it doesn't work, the program is stopped every time.

Function:

```
void rank_insert(ranklist *b, ranklist *first){
    ranklist *nw;
    int name_length;

    nw = (ranklist*) malloc(sizeof(*b));
    nw->point = b->point;
    name_length = strlen(b->name);
    nw->name = (char*) malloc(name_length + 1);
    nw->name = b->name;

    int element = 0;
    while(first != NULL){
        if (first->point > uj->point){
            if (first->next == NULL){
                nw->next = NULL;
                first->next = nw;
            }
            first = first->next;
            element++;
        }
        else if (first->point == uj->point){
                nw->next = first->next;
                first->next = nw;
        }
        else if (first->point < nw->point){
            if (element == 0){
                nw->next = first;
                first = nw;
            }
            else{
                nw->next = first->next;
                first->next = nw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a working read from file, write into a file, printf, and free functions

Comment: OK, it doesn't work.  Maybe you should debug it?

Answer (score 1):

this looks wrong:

```
nw->name = (char*) malloc(name_length + 1);
nw->name = b->name;
```

nw->name is a pointer.  C does not assign objects to pointers, it overwrites nw->name with b->name by value.  Try

```
nw->name = (char*) malloc(name_length + 1);
strcpy(nw->name, b->name, name_length);
nw->name[name_length] = '\0';
```

Also, I see `uj` used, but where is it defined?

The `first` needs to be returned, because the function can change the head of the list.

I don't think this loop handles insertion into an empty list.

the code is maintaining the list in descending order, except when `first->point < uj->point` and `element != 0`, when it puts uj after first.

The way to handle insertion into a singly linked list is to track the pointer that points to each element, to be able to inesrt either before or after.  So declare `ranklist **pptr = &first` and examine (*pptr)->point.  If it is smaller, `*pptr = uj` else `pptr = &(*pptr)->next;`

Kind of interesting reading code that only a bilingual Hungarian/English programmer can understand :-)

Comment: uj = nw, just i forgot translate it